# Neovim crashes after :help command when RubyGem is installed

Tags: ruby, neovim

### Cause of the problem

The problem is caused by some plugin called `LustyExplorer`. Normally, when I encounter some bug in Vim I always remove all plugins and customizations first. But after passing to Neovim, I forgot to do this first.

### Original Question

I have just recently installed `nvim 0.2.2` on OsX El Capitan v10.11.6 using the command: `brew install neovim`

```
$ brew info neovim
neovim: stable 0.2.2 (bottled), HEAD
Ambitious Vim-fork focused on extensibility and agility
https://neovim.io/
/usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.2.2 (1,374 files, 17.6MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2017-12-27 at 22:45:13
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/neovim.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: cmake ✘, lua@5.1 ✘, pkg-config ✔
Required: gettext ✔, jemalloc ✔, libtermkey ✔, libuv ✔, libvterm ✔, luajit ✔, msgpack ✔, unibilium ✔

$ nvim --version
NVIM v0.2.2
Build type: Release
LuaJIT 2.0.5
Compilation: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/super/clang -Wconversion -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -DNVIM_MSGPACK_HAS_FLOAT32 -DNVIM_UNIBI_HAS_VAR_FROM -DNDEBUG -DMIN_LOG_LEVEL=3 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wno-unused-parameter -Wstrict-prototypes -std=gnu99 -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wvla -fstack-protector-strong -fdiagnostics-color=auto -DINCLUDE_GENERATED_DECLARATIONS -I/tmp/neovim-20171118-36724-uevp4/neovim-0.2.2/build/config -I/tmp/neovim-20171118-36724-uevp4/neovim-0.2.2/src -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/include -I/tmp/neovim-20171118-36724-uevp4/neovim-0.2.2/build/src/nvim/auto -I/tmp/neovim-20171118-36724-uevp4/neovim-0.2.2/build/include
Compiled by brew@ElCapitan-2.local

Features: +acl +iconv +jemalloc +tui 
See ":help feature-compile"

   system vimrc file: "$VIM/sysinit.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.2.2/share/nvim"

Run :checkhealth for more info
```

`nvim` runs properly. But after installing `neovim` RubyGem, I cannot use `:help` command in `neovim`. The application crashes immediately:

```
$ gem install neovim
Fetching: neovim-0.6.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed neovim-0.6.2
1 gem installed
```

Executing `:help` command in `nvim` gives the following error message:

```
nvim(69661,0x7fff7274e000) malloc: *** error for object 0x7f9414310d00: pointer being freed was not allocated
   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
                                                  [1]    69661 abort      nvim
```

I use `rvm 1.26.11` to manage ruby.

```
$ rvm list

rvm rubies

=* ruby-2.1.1 [ x86_64 ]

$ rvm --version
rvm 1.26.11 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]

$ rvm gemdir
/Users/mertnuhoglu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1

$ gem --version
2.4.8
```